# adding to a javascript function using a html checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have seen some questions that answer adding to an object but I believe this is slightly different as it involves a html checkbox.

So i basically need to put in place a html checkbox that will add or subtract (depending on checked) the selection AU01,2,3,4 etc and apend it to the function i already have.  This is the function I have made.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var data = {};
      var featuresData = [];
      var emotionsData = {};
      var emotions = [{
        title: "Happiness",
        AUs: ["AU04", "AU12"]   //THIS IS THE BIT I WANT TO ADD TO
      }];
```

so where it says AUs: ["AU04", "AU12"]  I have currently set that at au4 and 12 but I am actually wanting to put the text "AU**" into that part of the function.   i want to be able to add in additionals (or subtract them) depending on which checkbox is clicked.  each checkbox will represent an AU.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: If you don't know how to use an `if` statement, you really need to stop and get a beginner's book on javascript.

Comment: You need more details here.  Your code doesn't match up with your question.   It looks like you want to support multiple `emotions` and within those `emotions` support multiple `AUs`.  This is an exercise in breaking down your logical pieces and conquering them 1 at a time.

Comment: ive reported that comment the logic is straightforward where it says AU04, AU12 i want to control that from a checkbox as explained in a pretty straightforward way , what part of the logic can you not breakdown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code, when the submit button is clicked, an empty array is created. Then we iterate over all checked checkboxes in specific div and push in that array its attribute values. Finally, the solution is printed out.

```js
$('#check').click(function(){
  var checked = [];
  $('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function(){
    checked.push($(this).attr('data-au'));
  });
  $('#out').text(JSON.stringify({AUs: checked}));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" data-au="au1" />au1<br />
  <input type="checkbox" data-au="au2" />au2<br />
  <input type="checkbox" data-au="au3" />au3<br />
  <input type="checkbox" data-au="au4" />au4<br />
</div>

<button id="check">check checkboxes</button>

<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Max that is very helpful , I may of not explained as well as perhaps I could , I am actually looking to change the AU's in the line of code depending on which checkbox is checked, does that make sense ?

Comment: So I made edits to fit your naming. You really should learn  js/jquery syntax more strictly if you cant understand something of it.

Comment: I appreciate that and thanks,  I wasnt quite too sure what '#out' was in reference to though i should of probably made clear that once the checkbox(s) has been selected then just a running of the functions is all that is required, sorry.

Comment: so basically , how to i change it so that i can append the current function instead of providing the text ?

Comment: var emotions = [{
        title: "Happiness",
        AUs: checked /* << HERE IS MAGIC */
      }];`

Comment: thanks so much ammend the variable to correspond with the checkbox

Comment: ahhh that didn't work